# Any way to force Mysql to use column from select in where clause when column is ambiguous?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have query:

```
select products.* from products
join companies on companies.id = products.company_id
where id = 1;
```

query generates error "Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous". I know that column is ambiguous, but I want tell mysql to look only columns in select "products.*". So if I have "products.*" id from products will be examined in where clause, if I have "companies.*" id from companies will be examined  in where clause, if I have "products.*, companies.*" only then id will be ambiguous.

This is just plain example, query is more complicated and generated by ORM. I know I can use

```
select products.id as products_id from products
```

and then use

```
where products_id  = 1
```

or I can use

```
where products.id = 1;
```

but this does not fit to my needs because query is generated by orm. Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried a `WHERE products.id = 1` yet?

Comment: This is a bad example. However - you can use a subquery.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This problem appears because I changed subqueries to join queries because they were 1000 times slower...

Comment: Subquery is a general solution. If you want a specific solution, your example should be more specific.

Comment: What i don't understand: At some point you have to decide which table to use in SELECT. So you have somewhere a code like `->select("{$tableName}.*")`. Why cann't you use the same variable for the WHERE clause: `->where("{$tableName}.id", 1)` ?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel because I sometines where is not used for base table, but I think my customizations in ORM are to complicated to paste this here...

Comment: I think there's no way to answer your question without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify from which table you want to use id as you wrote:

```
WHERE products.id = 1
```

When using eloquent you can do it in using DB::raw:

```
DB::table('products')
    ->select(DB::raw('products.*'))
    ->join('companies', DB::raw('companies.id'), '=', DB::raw('products.company_id'))
    ->where(DB::raw('products.id'), '=', 1)
    ->get()
;
```

Comment: Same as for the other answer: The table name in the WHERE clause is hardcoded, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: There was no information in question that he can't/doesn't want to hardcode table. There was just an info that he's using eloquent. He wrote this in comment AFTER my answer and AFTER your downvote.

Comment: The answer is not wrong. It's working even if it's not exactly what he wanted - it's not possible to predict what he wants if he didn't write it.

Answer (score -2):

```
select products.* from products
join companies on companies.id = products.company_id
where products.id = 1;
```

Comment: Please read the question. OP doesn't want to hardcode the table prefix in the where clause.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel he didn't write that. He just wrote he doesn't know how to do this using eloquent.